# Adding autocomplete to Google CSE based on taxonomy terms

Tags: 6, search

I want to implement something similar to the search on http://www.retailmenot.com/. When you type in a company name, a drop down will appear showing you matching companies. I want to do the same thing on my Drupal and have the suggestions be terms from a certain vocabulary. I am also using Google CSE. Does anyone know how I can implement this using modules or how to start if I wanted to code this myself?

Comment: Hey Matthew, did you ever find a solution to this question? I need similar help, please.